# Зачем в большом количестве используют тег i?

Tags: html, design, css

Все чаще и чаще замечаю, что в туториалах на сайтах разработчиков плагинов появляется      тег `< i>`, зачем? Его очень часто используют, но не пойму, в чем его преимущество.

Примерно так:

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```

P.S. Про эффект тега знаю.

Comment: 1. Он короткий. 2. Его никто давно не использует, поэтому коллизия маловероятна. 3. А хз.

Comment: Что такое коллизия в html?

Comment: Кажется, понял, это если кто-то добавит свой кусок кода, и там будет такой же блок с таким же классом? И они будут пересекаться

Comment: @Юра Сучко, маловероятно, что на нем уже висят стили от разработчика.

Comment: i >>>>>>>> icon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Короткий

Answer (score 2):

В настоящее время его используют для иконок.

Comment: ... в основном в цсс фреймворках

Answer (score 2):

Используют из-за собственной лени - это единственное объяснение.
Если не вспоминать, для чего изначально был придуман этот тег, можно еще допустить следование за модным бутстрапом (ну как же, бутстрап - это авторитет), хотя именно разработчикам бутстрапа я обязан постоянному потоку присылаемых на доработку проектов))).
Если внимательно глянуть на большинство BS-шаблонов, где надо и где не надо используются заголовки h2-h4, те же i, и не побоюсь этого слова - EM! EM, Карл! Про теги b и  strong нужно наверно промолчать. лет 10 назад это было бы конечно абсолютно без разницы и всякий начинающий верстальщик с радостью вставлял H3 - опля и жирный текст сразу и размер шрифта не надо присваивать))) А сейчас поисковики начали делать добрые дела - разбирать зерна меж плевел.
В свои проектах для таких вещей, для которых большинство применяет тег i, активно применяю псевдотеги before и after - в коде страницы вообще нет мусора! Попробуйте, вам понравится!

Comment: ну <b>, <strong> и подобные - это актуальные теги, для семантической верстки, их нельзя так выкинуть.

Comment: для акцента контентной части - да, но никак не для оформления - для иконок, пунктов меню и так далее! я имел ввиду сугубо шаблон, не текстовую составляющую...